# DSN Creation using C# windows application form

Tags: c#

HI everyone i am beginner in C# so i need help. I am making C# windows application forms and using Class and used a Button to call a class but i dont know how to call a class by clicking button. help will be appreciated. i am creating another form and only 1 button it contains, the DSN NAME i want to create is "Fassets" Database name is also Fassets
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs1uk.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace dsn
{
   public static class Class1
   {
       private const string ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
       private const string ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";

       /// <summary>
       /// Creates a new DSN entry with the specified values. If the DSN exists, the values are updated.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="dsnName">Name of the DSN for use by client applications</param>
       /// <param name="description">Description of the DSN that appears in the ODBC control panel applet</param>
       /// <param name="server">Network name or IP address of database server</param>
       /// <param name="driverName">Name of the driver to use</param>
       /// <param name="trustedConnection">True to use NT authentication, false to require applications to supply username/password in the connection string</param>
       /// <param name="database">Name of the datbase to connect to</param>
       public static void CreateDSN(string dsnName, string description, string server, string driverName, bool trustedConnection, string database)
       {
           // Lookup driver path from driver name
           var driverKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + driverName);
           if (driverKey == null) throw new Exception(string.Format("ODBC Registry key for driver '{0}' does not exist", driverName));
           string driverPath = driverKey.GetValue("Driver").ToString();

           // Add value to odbc data sources
           var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
           if (datasourcesKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for datasources does not exist");
           datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);

           // Create new key in odbc.ini with dsn name and add values
           var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + dsnName);
           if (dsnKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created");
           dsnKey.SetValue("Fassets", database);
           dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);
           dsnKey.SetValue("driverPath", driverPath);
           dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", Environment.UserName);
           dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);
           dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
           dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Removes a DSN entry
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="dsnName">Name of the DSN to remove.</param>
       public static void RemoveDSN(string dsnName)
       {
           // Remove DSN key
           Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + dsnName);

           // Remove DSN name from values list in ODBC Data Sources key
           var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
           if (datasourcesKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for datasources does not exist");
           datasourcesKey.DeleteValue(dsnName);
       }

       ///<summary>
       /// Checks the registry to see if a DSN exists with the specified name
       ///</summary>
       ///<param name="dsnName"></param>
       ///<returns></returns>
       public static bool DSNExists(string dsnName)
       {
           var driversKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Drivers");
           if (driversKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for drivers does not exist");

           return driversKey.GetValue(dsnName) != null;
       }

       ///<summary>
       /// Returns an array of driver names installed on the system
       ///</summary>
       ///<returns></returns>
       public static string[] GetInstalledDrivers()
       {
           var driversKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Drivers");
           if (driversKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for drivers does not exist");

           var driverNames = driversKey.GetValueNames();

           var ret = new List<string>();

           foreach (var driverName in driverNames)
           {
               if (driverName != "(Default)")
               {
                   ret.Add(driverName);
               }
           }

           return ret.ToArray();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: VS does not run automatically with "As Admin" credentials and uses your regular credentials.  You need to start VS by right click VS shortcut and select "Run As Admin".  The Net executable does run with "As Admin".  The DNS requires Admin to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to bind a 'click' event to a button and run a method from your class Class. Just double click the button in the designer and you will be let to a just created function. In this function you can call the function from your class.

Please note!
Please never use Class as name of a class. It's a reserved word. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: yes i want to run a method from my class in click button on another form. but i dont know how to do i am newbie in C#

Comment: I dont know how to call a function from a class